# How to design the db for column update voting system?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Assuming that the db has a table 'houses' -> house_id(pk) | color | nbr_of_windows;

The houses table is populated by 1 user but later , if a column has to be updated , the update will be finalised only if a number of users agree on it. Should I make another 2 tables that will store data about update proposals (the voting system data) for each houses table column? Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Better is a subjective term.  No one here understands your requirements better than you.  Do you need to be able to scale over time? What happens if attributes change? If you anticipate the number of house attributes to increase, you might be better off keeping multiple tables: House, HouseAttributes Attribute, Change, ChangeHouseAttributes.  Votes would be recorded in ChangeHouseAttributes, changeRecord would be kept in Change with details of change in ChangeHouseAttributes.  This way you can see who's requesting changes track to the houseattributes being changed.

Comment: @xQbert Ty for your response . Yeah, the final decison it's up to me . I was just hoping for some magical pattern that i haven't heared of :D or some mix of hierarchies and polymorphic associations :D thought some1 stumbled across this and would share the experience :)

Comment: The best solution is always the one that solve your current request: performance AND/OR scalability AND/OR maintenance AND/OR "academic" AND/OR ... :)